# How to put an image next to each other

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to put these two 'hyperlinked' icons next to each other but I can't seem to do that. As you can see, the twitter icon falls to the next line.. (they are both hyperlinked to their respective website)

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="nav3" style="height:705px;">
    <div id="icons"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="icons"><a href="https://twitter.com"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav3 {
    background-color: #E9E8C7;
    height: auto;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333333;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#icons{position:relative; 
    width: 64px; 
    height: 64px; 
   }

    #icons a:hover {
     background: #C93;
        display: block;

 }
```

How do I make the aligned next to each other?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried `display : 'inline'` ?

Comment: btw: you can't have two ID's with the same value in one HTML file, you'd better change it to class and then change all the `#icons` in the css to `.icons`

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work on my browser but it works on jsfiddle.. hmm..

Comment: @MikeB that works but the hover screws up :/

Comment: @ja will do that! thanks!

Comment: although one more thing which is not relative to this, but you can follow, use css image sprite http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Answer (score 16):

You don't need the div's.

HTML:

```
<div class="nav3" style="height:705px;">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" class="icons"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com" class="icons"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav3 {
    background-color: #E9E8C7;
    height: auto;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333333;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.icons{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 64px; 
    height: 64px; 
   }

 a.icons:hover {
     background: #C93;
 }
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Un8J/)

Comment: No problem. hopefully it's a bit understandable

Comment: @jao He may need them later.

Comment: @user2320517 If you need div to style the content later, use span as shown in my answer.

Comment: ok! i'll have a look! thanks for the help. greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take note: inline-block is not supported on old ie browsers. I honestly prefer float, it works like charm in all browser-old or new.

Comment: with float you might need a clearing float as [explained here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Answer (score 6):

Change div to span. And space the icons using `&nbsp;`
HTML

```
 <div class="nav3" style="height:705px;">
 <span class="icons"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
 </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <span class="icons"><a href="https://twitter.com"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a>
 </span>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.nav3 {
background-color: #E9E8C7;
height: auto;
width: 150px;
float: left;
padding-left: 20px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #333333;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
}

.icons{
display:inline-block;
width: 64px; 
height: 64px; 
}

 a.icons:hover {
 background: #C93;
 }
```

span does not break line, div does.

Comment: Spacing using &nbsp; is soooo last century.

Comment: so @MrLister what's 21st century? of course we can use that too.

Comment: using `position:absolute;` is also an option. Or `padding`.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit obsolete, but in some cases sufficient enough. Nowadays it could be: `span.icons { margin-left:2em; display:inline-block }` or something like that :-)

Comment: Yes, css. You can also use `margin`, transparent `border`, increase the `width`...

Comment: okay cool. `&nbsp;` was the first thing that came to my mind. Thanks for suggestions, I would try to be little 'modern' next time.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out. Just use float and get rid of relative.

http://jsfiddle.net/JhpRk/

```
#icons{float:left;}
```

Comment: looks ok, just don't duplicate div id's - use the same class
http://jsfiddle.net/JhpRk/228/

Comment: This really works. Needs to be the acepted answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try putting both images next to each other. Like this:

```html
    <div id="icons"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a><a href="https://twitter.com"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: oops. the code didn't show... but I hope you know what I mean

Comment: You need to put HTML inside "code fences" - I've done it for you, this time!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `position:relative` in `#icons`, you could just take that away and maybe add a z-index or something so the picture won't get covered up. Hope this helps.