# I want to upload an image with its original size and put it in a div with fixed size

Tags: css, asp.net

I have an image tag :

```
 <div id="original"><img id="img1" runat="server" src="" /></div>
```

I want to upload the original image (original width and height) in div "original" which has a fixed height and width (500px each).

**for ex**: If I uploaded an image (50*50) appears in div "original" without affecting its h & w.

I can change the div into a rectangle for ex or something like a fixed frame size if this is better than a div. help me please and give me the best idea.

And please if I want to put another image beside the original one in another div what is the right `css` code that makes it on the right of the original one.

Comment: Have you tried just using `max-width` and `max-height`?... in fact, have you tried anything at all?

Comment: i have tried to add css (width and height) to the id "original" and the image that i uploaded has 50*50 but it appears with the width and height of the div

Comment: it is not very clear what you are trying to do? why don't you set the fixed height and width to your img tag?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to add dimensions to the div instead of the image. If you put an image of any size in a div of fixed size, the image size is retained. So, If you intend to restrict the image size, set style for image with the image id.

To answer the second part of your question, refer to the foll. link:
[How to put an image next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260485/how-to-put-an-image-next-to-each-other)

You might have to make a few changes in the style for div according to your images and their dimensions. But, a little tweaking would work.

Comment: thanks a lot :) the reason is that i want to make the div as a background of that image so that i can change the color of it and stuff like that

Comment: You can add colors and all the other stuff, there is no issue with having that div. But, I suggest do the sizing on the image.

Comment: how to change the background color of a textbox using color picker in c#

Comment: I would recommend asking this in a new question. Even then i hope this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/ajax-control-toolkit/colorpicker/using-the-colorpicker-control-extender-cs) helps. Also, Mark the answer as solved, if it solved your problem.