# Best solution to display horizontal and vertical images next to each other

Tags: html, css, image

I'm currently running out of ideas while building websites here and there with some images next to each other. There are horizontal and vertical images and i want to display them all on the same size. Anybody know a good solution for this problem?

[image: Example of my Problem]

Here's a [demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/LjMBjY?editors=1100)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: visible;
  padding: 0;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 200px;
}

img {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<h2>list of different sized images</h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/150/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/120/180/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/180/120/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/180/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/120/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please post your code which you have tried and also the css.

Comment: You can't. You either have to crop or stretch the images to a common size. Another option is to use masonry on the item containers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put an image next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260485/how-to-put-an-image-next-to-each-other)

Comment: @Jopy Downstair I took the liberty to add some demo code to your question - if that's not what you meant - then I'll revert this edit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

1) Set `display:flex` on the container to maintain consistent height for the items.

2) Set `object-fit: cover` on the images. **NB:** This will crop the images.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) on `object-fit: cover`

> **cover**
>
> The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while
>   filling the element’s entire content box. If the object's aspect ratio
>   does not match the aspect ratio of its box, then the object will be
>   clipped to fit.

```
.crop img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px; /* optional */
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: visible;
  padding: 0;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 200px;
}

img {
  border: 5px solid green;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.crop img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px; /* optional */
}
```

```html
<h2>BEFORE: list of different sized images</h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/150/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/120/180/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/180/120/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/180/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/120/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>

<hr>
<h2>AFTER: A list with display:flex and object-fit:cover applied</h2>
<ul class="flex crop">
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/150/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/120/180/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/180/120/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/180/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/120/animals" alt="">
      <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/QMzBEO)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#picture1: {width:'size'; height:'size'; }` for making the pictures the same size.

Take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_img_width.asp